# I don't understand why this code don't work the for int error

Tags: java, error-handling

I dont understand why this code dont work the for int error.
I tried using the following code:

```java
package com.example.android.touregiude;

import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.location.Location;

import com.example.android.cairotourguide.R;

public class hotelsFragment extends CategoryAbstractFragment {
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public hotelsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Overridden methods
     */
    @Override
    void populateLocationsList() {
        String[] LocationsNames = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Hotels_names);
        String[] LocationsAddresses = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Hotels_addresses);
        String[] LocationsPhoneNumbers = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Hotels_phone_numbers);
        TypedArray LocationsImagesResIds = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.Hotels_images);

        for (int i = 0; i < LocationsNames.length; ++i) {
            locationsList.add(new Location (LocationsNames[i],
                    LocationsAddresses[i],
                    getString(R.string.Location_open_24_hours),
                    LocationsPhoneNumbers[i],
                    getString(R.string.Location_wiki_url_not_provided_text),
                    LocationsImagesResIds.getResourceId(i,0)));
        }

        LocationsImagesResIds.recycle();
    }


}
```

The encountered error:

```
error: no suitable constructor found for
Location(String,String,String,String,String,int) constructor
Location.Location(String) is not applicable (actual and formal
argument lists differ in length) constructor
Location.Location(Location) is not applicable (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are accidentally importing [Location from the Android API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html), which only accepts one `String` or `Location` as constructor argument, instead your own `Location`.
In that case, just adapt the line `import android.location.Location;` to import your custom class.